# reading xml in matlab by using xml2struct

Tags: xml, matlab

I'm trying to convert xml files into a struct in matlab by using xml2struct function, but i always run into some unwanted errors.

Here's an example:

This is the XML file i want to convert.

[image]

When i use the function in matlab i get this result:

[image]

I thought/hoped that my string ("paper") would be my Data - where you can see the 'red 1'.

Instead the function found a children called "#text" and my data got into it's structure with some additional signs.

I tried playing with different settings, like changing file coding but it didnt help.
Even if i remove all the new line characters and my file become a one line string(which is totally unreadable for me especially in bigger files) still got the main issue:

The "simplified" file:

[image]

Results:

[image]

If i want to read larger files every second sub-element is a "#text":

[image]

[image]

1, How can i clear the new line characters without making my file into a one-line string?

2, In my opinion it isn't supposed to work this way - the "pencil" string should be the Data in my main structure, not below it.

3, How could i get rid of the "#text" elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is: are you sure that you are using [the last version](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/58700-xml2struct---with-bug-fix-and-added-features) of `xml2struct`? Because I downloaded that one in order to make a test and everything looks fine to me on the point of view of the structure returned:

[image: Screen]

The same goes for the line breaks. It seems that the script is correctly trimming the Text properties of the XML tags on both sides.

I think that the common root of all your problems is the fact you choose an old version of the script to perform your parsing. If you don't want to rely on a custom script to parse and traverse XML files, you can always use the built-in [xmlread function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlread.html), which uses the underlying Java framework to handle everything and could be more reliable (but obviously a little bit harder to use).

On a side note, never forget to add a proper declaration to your XML files, on the top, before the document root:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
```

Comment: He was using xm2struct from Bioinformatics Toolbox and you were using xml2struct from fileexchange.